# Return Value of apply-partially

Tags: elisp, apply

I'm playing around with `apply-partially` and I'm confused about what gets returned when calling this function. The documentation states that `apply-partially` returns a function, but then I'd expect to be able to do the following:

```
(defun add-numbers (a b)
  (+ a b))
(defun add2 (apply-partially 'add-numbers 2))
```

and then call the function:

```
(add2 3)
```

OR:

```
(funcall add2 3)
```

Unfortunately this throws an error. When I do everything inside of a `let`, however, it does work and I get "5" back:

```
(let ((add2 (apply-partially 'add-numbers 2)))
  (funcall add2 3))
```

I thought maybe the difference was that let doesn't use `defun`, as I do above, but then I would expect the following to work:

```
(defvar add2 (apply-partially 'add-numbers 2))
(funcall
 add2 3)
```

but that doesn't work either. So what am I missing? Is it not possible to assign the return value of `apply-partially` outside of a `let`?

Comment: Wait, I see now, that my `(defun add2 (....))` can't work because `defun` sees `(apply-partially 'add-numbers 2)` as an argument list. `apply-partially` never actually gets called here. So that means the `(defun add (...))` call CAN'T work, leaving only the `(defvar add2 (...))` towards the bottom.

Comment: You could also use `defalias`

Comment: You're right, using `defalias` allows me to call the return value of `apply-partially` in the following way: `(add2 3)`, i.e. as a normal function. `(funcall add2 3)` doesn't work, but that's also not a problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. As noted in my comment above, my code:

```
(defun add2 (apply-partially 'add-numbers 2))
```

can't work because `defun` is a special form and `(apply-partially 'add-numbers 2)` is seen as the argument list to the special form, i.e. `apply-partially` never gets evaluated.

This leaves us with the challenge of saving the call `(apply-partially 'add-numbers 2)` to something else that can either be called directly, i.e. `(add2 3)` or with `(funcall add2 33)`. As mentioned, my attempt with `defvar` above doesn't work:

```
(defvar add2 (apply-partially 'add-numbers 2))
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943606/921319), and has to do with the  fact "... that in Emacs Lisp, symbols have a value cell and a function cell, which are distinct. When you evaluate a symbol, you get its value. When you evaluate a list beginning with that symbol, you call its function. This is why you can have a variable and a function with the same name."

So can replace `defvar` with `setq` and `(funcall add2 3)` will work as expected. Otherwise, we can also use `fset` to set the returned value of `apply-partially` directly to `add2`'s function cell:

```
(fset 'add2 (apply-partially 'add-numbers 2))
```

and then we can simply call the function: `(add2 3)`

Comment: The `defvar` + `funcall` example works for me.

Comment: Am I using `defvar` wrong? I keep getting "Symbol's function definition is void: nil" when I use `defvar` + `funcall`

Comment: Maybe you have set the `add2` variable earlier in the session? See the docstring of `defvar`: `...set SYMBOL, only if SYMBOL's value is void.`